# Why doesn't this numpy slicing operation, which I don't have a good name for, not work?

Tags: numpy

I do not understand why my slicing operation does not work. My intention is to apply the slice [::2] to each sub array of a so that the size of x is (3, 5), but things don't go as expected.

```
a = np.arange(0,30)
a.shape = (3, -1)
x = a[:][::2]

a : array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
          [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
          [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

The actual output is

```
x: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

The desired output is

```
x : array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
          [10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
          [20, 22, 24, 26, 28])
```

Comment: Indexing with `[:]` does nothing for you.

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
x = a[:,::2]
```

Otherwise you select the full array on the first dimension, and then do the same again, one the first dimension, not the second.